# Questions about the New Ancestry transition?

Tags: discussion

We have a question [Getting Ancestry.com to show "view relationship to me" on profiles?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/10039/1006) about a problem which was caused by the transition from what is called "Classic" Ancestry to "New Ancestry".

Since the problem is not resolved yet, and the situation may be in flux for some time, I have answered the question and marked it as Community Wiki.  I can see where it would be useful to share the information about the progress (or lack of it) for this feature being restored, but it's not what I would call a real answer.

I've also created a new tag to flag the questions that specifically deal with issues coming about because of this 14/15 December 2015 changeover.

This is what seems best to me as I write this -- but I'd like to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that we need a [new-ancestry](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-ancestry) tag because we will no longer be able to access "Classic" Ancestry.com anyway.

I'm also not sure about the need to turn your answer into a Community Wiki, but certainly there is no harm in doing so.

Personally, I think the thing that will bring the most pressure to bear on Ancestry.com is if posts here that highlight "lost" features are highly upvoted.  I would be surprised if no one from Ancestry.com ever comes here to check either:

- our [self-assembling FAQ on Ancestry.com](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancestry.com?sort=frequent) or
- our [most upvoted questions about Ancestry.com](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancestry.com?sort=votes).

I think our target should be for one of our posts to appear high on the results returned by: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22view+relationship+to+me%22

Comment: My thoughts were that tag:new-ancestry would be for posts that dealt specifically with the features that were broken by the transition, as opposed to questions about looking for records. And I would be surprised if Ancestry paid much attention to what was said here -- they seem to be very busy already ignoring the complaints from customers on their own company sites.